# Remove the custom patch in magento 2.2.5

Tags: patches, magento-2.2.5

I want to remove the custom patch applied to the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with remove ? 
If you want to revert it , use this :

```
git apply -R <path to name-of-the-patch.patch>
```

**Hard Way**

If you applied a patch ,definetly you have added it with composer , so when the patch was generated , he modified the vendor . 
If , for example you have made a patch that have modified `vendor/magento/module-catalog` , you have to remove

`rm -rf vendor/magento/module-catalog`

Open composer.json , find the correct name of the patch applied in composer.json and remove the line.

Run `composer install` to regenerate the composer.lock and vendor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes I want to revert it. But using this I am getting some errors.

Comment: what errors ? Update your question please

Comment: In Magento cloud, we can't use this command?

Comment: Updated my answer , check please.

Comment: But one problem we don't have permission to delete or update in cloud